# Creating a Hard Link in java

Tags: java, operating-system

Currently I use '`ln`' command via `Runtime.exec()`. It works fine. The only problem is that in order to do this fork, we need twice the heap space of the application. My app is a 64 bit app with heap size around 10Gigs and thus its runs out of swap space. I couldn't find any configuration that could fix this.

I also want not to use JNI for the same.
Also I had heard somewhere that this facility will soon be provided in java 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) in place of JNI (JNA has some clear advantages over JNI); yes, check the [JSR 203](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=203)

Answer (score 15):

It’s easy in Java 7 using [createLink](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createLink(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path)):

```
Files.createLink(Paths.get("newlink"), Paths.get("existing"));
```

Comment: Here is the documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy with JNA:

```
public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)
        Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "msvcrt" : "c"),
                           CLibrary.class);
    int link(String fromFile, String toFile);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CLibrary.INSTANCE.link(args[0], args[1]);
}
```

Compile and run!

Comment: It compiles, but it does not run. Not under Windows, that is. I haven’d yet groked the magic that JNA performs, but it seems the name of the respective function in MSVCRT is very different.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015006/whats-the-name-of-the-create-hard-link-function-in-msvcrt, the function is called `CreateHardLink` and it's located in Kernel32, not in MSVCRT (which makes sense).

Answer (score -3):

You could use Windows instead of UNIX? ;) I believe JDK7 will be using a call similar to CreateProcess instead of fork where available.

A more practical solution would be to create a new child process soon after starting. If you are using a 10g heap, another small Java process probably wont be so bad. Get that process (via use of streams) to exec.