# What's the name of the "create hard link" function in MSVCRT?

Tags: msvcrt, hardlink

To fix a bug in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783075/creating-a-hard-link-in-java/3023349#3023349): What's the correct name of the function to create a hard link in MSVCRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, there's a function called [`CreateHardLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  But it doesn't live in MSVCRT; it's part of Kernel32.