# How to calculate hardlink, owner & group of a file using java6 code?

Tags: java, groovy

This is a continuation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214359/how-to-collect-directory-listing-along-with-each-file-crc-checksum). Is there a way to calculate `hardlink, owner & group` using java6?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 6, all you can do is call `Runtime.exec("ls -li "+filename)` and parse its output.

Java 7 has more support for file permissions and links, but I haven't used these APIs.

Comment: Is there any third party library for java that I can use to get these along with file `permissions`?

Comment: You can use JNA like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783075/creating-a-hard-link-in-java